# Consider the set in $\Bbb{R}^3$ given by: $P1 = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 : |x| \le 1\, |y| \le 1\, |z| \le 1\}$. Show that the set is a polyhedron

Tags: optimization, proof-writing, solution-verification, polyhedra

I am encountering trouble with this mathematical proof question for an optimisation context.

Question : Consider the set in $\Bbb{R}^3$ given by: $P1 = \{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb{R}^3 : |x| \le 1\, |y| \le 1\, |z| \le 1\}$. Show that the set is a polyhedron

A polyhedron $P ⊆ \Bbb{R}^n$ is the set of all points $x ∈ \Bbb{R}^n$ that satisfy a finite set of linear inequalities.
Mathematically, the definition of a polyhedron would be (definition - a) Polyhedron = $\{x | Ax \ge b\}$. For some matrix $A ∈ \Bbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and a vector $b ∈ \Bbb{R}^m$.

More interestingly, the definition of a polyhedron can also equal to Polyhedron = $\{x | Ax \le b\}$. (Definition - b)

Although there are $2$ definitions and I would like to prove using definition A, I feel that presently, it would be easier to prove using definition b first, and then use it as a springboard to prove using definition A. This is because I feel as the question uses ${\le}$ for the absolute values of x,y and z.

I have separated the absolute value equations into 6 equations such as $|x| {\le 1}$ into $+x {\le 1}$ and $-x {\le 1}$ and continuing for $y$ and $z$. I know the $x$ matrix in the polyhedron corresponds to the $x,y$ and $z$ variables in the set.

1. However, I am confused about the next step of translating these 6 sets of equations, namely
   $+x {\le 1}$ and $-x {\le 1}$, $+y {\le 1}$ and $-y {\le 1}$, $+z {\le 1}$ and $-z {\le 1}$ into the polyhedron definition of Polyhedron = $\{x | Ax \le b\}$ for the proof. Would it simply suffice to substitute all the coefficient of the equations into $A$ such that it is a $6 \times 3$ matrix and showing $b$ as a column vector of $1$ for the final step in the proof, or would further steps need to be taken? Any method would also be appreciated
2. Next it is still the same question problem in the title. As shown in point $1$, I was trying to prove the set to be a polyhedron using definition $2$. However, I would still like to prove using definition 1 and my intent is to use the point 1 as a springboard. Assuming I am using the method in point 1 such that $\{x | Ax \le b\}$ with $A$ as a $6 \times 3$ matrix using the coefficients of the $6$ equations earlier,I am trying to prove using definition $1$ as an end-goal, that is $\{x | Ax \ge b\}$. For this $\{Ax \le b\}$ part, I have a negative sign forming $\{-Ax \ge -b\}$ to change the negative sign. However, I was wondering how to convert this to a Polyhedron = $\{x | Ax \ge b\}$ as there are now negative signs.

Again, any method would be appreciated if there is a flaw in my approach.

Please help me with this question and thank you guys!

Comment: What is $\,x\,$ in your definition of a polyhedron? Even better, [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4375203/edit) the question and copy the definition you are using literally, since your paraphrase doesn't look quite right.

Comment: Thanks Dvix for your response :) I will edit the definition more clearly.

Comment: Everything you say is correct. First, you described your set by 6 linear inequalities (personally I think the proof should end here, but if you insist on fitting one of the formal representations then OK). Then you say you will turn these inequalities into a 6x3 matrix description $Ax\leq b$, and that is also fine. Finally you observe that from this representation you can get the other representation as $(-A)x\geq (-b)$. That is also correct. So you are good all the way. Good job.

Comment: At least, do you realize that this polyedron is a cube ? I don't see it mentionned...

Comment: Why don't you consider another definition of a (convex) polyhedron which is a "nonvoid set intersection of halfspaces" ?

Comment: Thank you Dr Michal for your clarification about my concerns!

Comment: Thanks Dr Marie for your response! Yes you are right, it is a cube. I have just realised this after drawing the points 3-dimensionally as I am trying to find the extreme points of the set too. 

Could you please explain more about the approach for the "non void set intersection of half spaces" as I am not so familiar with this definition aspect. This concept is rather new to me and it would be enlightening to have a different approach. 

Separately, would you consider the approach posted in the question above to be logically correct too?

Comment: I wasn't aware of your answer because you hadn't prefixed it by the arrowbas followed by my pseudo. See https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis610/convex45.pdf . Yes your approach is correct.

Comment: I would like to seek help for an additional problem relating to this same set (mentioned in the question), specifically to find the extreme points of this set. Just would like to confirm, the cube which was previously mentioned in our earlier discussion would be ranging from -1 to 1 in the xyz plane right and not 0 to 1? For this question, I have managed to graph it and I realised the extreme points would be a total of 8 combinations of +/- 1 points for each axis such as (-1,+1,-1). Would there be a more convenient algebraic way to find these extreme points besides finding combinations of 3 eq

Comment: you simply have to observe that any of the given 3 relations in fact each is composed of 2 relations each: eg. $|x|\le 1$ means $x\le 1$ and $-x\le 1$.